# type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'sparse'

Tags: nlp, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse
_vectorized = count_vectorizer.transform(data['text'])
_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(_vectorized)
```

Why is the error occuring. I'm working on Jupyter based environment kaggle and azure notebook. Error shows up both of the place. But On spyder it's working perfectly. What am I missing?

Comment: What pandas version do you use? .sparse only added at v0.25

Comment: Yeah I was using pandas 0.23. So that was the issue. Thanks. @LiadMagen

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**
_dataframe = pd.SparseDataFrame(_vectorized)